# I'm having problems fixing my "getters" and "setters" in inheritance

Tags: java

Please bear with me, this is my first time dealing with inheritance in Java. :)

I have the following superclass which identifies ships and returns a name of the ship and its length:

```
public class Ship {

    private String name="";
    private int length=0;

    public Ship(String name, int length) {
        this.setName(name);
        this.length = length;
    }

    public static String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Ship.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return " Ship "+name+" l="+ length ;
    }

}
```

This is done by creating an object such as:

```
Ship SSAnne = new Ship("S.S. Anne", 45);
```

Then I have "sub-classes" that extend from my superclass which define objects Container Ships, Tankers, and Cruise Ships. Here is my sub-class for container ships (the other types of ships are identical, except for different variable names):

```
public class ContainerShip extends Ship {

    private int teu=0;

    public ContainerShip(String string, int length, int teu) {
        super(getName(), length);
        this.teu = teu;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        ContainerShip.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return super.toString()+" container carrier with "+teu+" TEU";
    }

}
```

These sub-classes are called like this:

```
ContainerShip dave = new ContainerShip("Dave Oest", 100, 2000);
```

Where an extra variable is added and the first two arguments are the same variables from the superclass.

My issue is with my getters and setters for the "name" variable. When I run my code, it generates the "S.S. Anne" name for all objects, even the objects from the sub-classes. I can't seem to get it to "get" the name of the ships for my sub-classes.

Can anybody help me how to properly set up the getters and setters in my sub-classes?

---

@GBlodgett:

```
public class Ship {

    private String name="";
    private int length=0;

    public Ship(String name, int length) {
        this.setName(name);
        this.length = length;
    }

    public void getName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return " Ship "+name+" l="+ length ;
    }

}

public class ContainerShip extends Ship {

    private int teu=0;

    public ContainerShip(String string, int length, int teu) {
        super(getName(), length);
        this.teu = teu;
    }

    public void getName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return super.toString()+" container carrier with "+teu+" TEU";
    }

}
```

Comment: You should have some warnings and error on your code to tell you about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared `name` as `static`, which means there's only one copy shared among all instances of the class. You want to remove the `static` keyword, and then in your getters and setters, use the [`this`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) keyword, which refers to the object the method is invoked on:

```
 public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

In which case the `setName` method will be the same in both classes and you will not need to override it in the subclass

---

The first problem with your updated code is that you cannot refer to an instance method while explicitly invoking a constructor. Instead of calling `getName()`, pass the `String` argument you pass into the constructor:

```
public SubClass(String string, int length, int teu) {
    super(string, length);
    this.teu = teu;
}
```

Then in your `getName()` method, you are treating it as a setter. You should instead return the `name` field:

```
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}
```

This leads to your last problem: You are using the superclass copy of `name`. Because you marked it as private, it will not be accessible to other classes. You can either give `ContainerShip` it's own `name` variable, or make the `name` in `Ship` protected, or use `super` again like:

```
public void setName(String name) {
    super.setName(name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I changed the declaration to `private String name="";` but I'm having a bit difficulty figuring out where to put my "this" keyword. It seems to give me an error "The field Ship.name is not visible" when I add the keyword. Am I supposed to do it in both my superclass and subclass?

Comment: @WoeIs Where are you adding the `this` keyword? Are you doing it like posted in my answer?

Comment: I edited my main post and pasted my updated code below. I'm getting the error in my sub-class.

Comment: I'm getting 3 errors in the subclass. At `getName()` it says "The method getName(String) in the type ContainerShip is not applicable for the arguments ()". Then at the `this.name` in both my getter and setter it says "The field Ship.name is not visible".

Comment: Thank you for the update. I finally managed to get it to work, and you were correct in your suggestions. I noticed however that the getters and setters in my subclass were redundant, so when I removed them from my subclass and only kept the getters and setters in my superclass, then it was able to still retrieve the names and also keep the declaration as private. Thank you again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can't access instance variables from static methods,

```
private String name="";
private int length=0;
```

These are instance variables, where as your method is declared as `static`

```
public static String getName() {
```

One key thing you should always remember while implementing **inheritance**.

Do not use static word with variable declaration or use static word in method declaration.

Inheritance only happens when we deal everything with instance variables and instance (non-static) methods. So you will have to change couple of things,

Change this,

```
public static String getName() {
```

to,

```
public String getName() {
```

Similarly, you can't access instance variables with class name and for referring to the current object, you can use `this`. Hence change,

```
public void setName(String name) {
    Ship.name = name;
}
```

to

```
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Also, in this constructor you have a problem,

```
public ContainerShip(String string, int length, int teu) {
    super(getName(), length);
    this.teu = teu;
}
```

You aren't using `string` variable that is your first parameter. You need to change this super class from this,

```
super(getName(), length);
```

to,

```
super(string, length);
```

This way, whatever was passed to constructor, will get passed to constructor of super class.

You should fix these problems first.

Also, once you create an object using `ContainerShip` class, it will have access to getter/setter methods from parent class `Ship` as your sub class will inherit those methods which is called inheritance. Its a broad subject and as you proceed, you will know more such constructs. Let me know if you further have any query regarding inheritance.

As you have declared your instance variables in super class as `private`, your instance variables aren't visible directly to sub classes, and only available through public getter/setter, but in case you want to directly access them, you can declare them as protected and can directly access them. Inheritance is the reason you can access variables from super class in sub class provided they are not declared as private. `Private` means only accessible in its own class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I removed all static keywords and added the "string" argument to my superclass method. When I changed private to proteced in my declaration, it appears to now work. However, is there not any solution where I can declare the "name" variable as private? Do I need to declare it private for all my subclasses?

Comment: No, no, you can declare instance variables as private but then they won't be directly accessible to sub classes and still you can make them available by public getter/setters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Interfaces to define Type and Abstract classes to define default behavior. For instance:

```
interface Ship {
    String getName();
    void setName();
}

abstract class DefaultShip implements Ship {
    private int length;

    public DefaultShip(int length) {
        this.length = length;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return " Ship " + getName() + " l=" + this.length;
    }
}

public class ContainerShip extends DefaultShip {

    private int teu;
    private String name;

    public ContainerShip(String name, int length, int teu) {
        super(length);
        this.name = name;
        this.teu = teu;
    }

    public void getName(String name) {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() +" container carrier with " + this.teu + " TEU";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need setters and getters in the sub-class for name and length values.
Only if you want to override them.

**Ship superclass**

```
public class Ship {

    private String name;
    private int length;

    public Ship(String name, int length) {
        this.name = name;
        this.length = length;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return " Ship "+name+" l="+ length ;
    }

}
```

**ContainerShip subclass**

```
public class ContainerShip extends Ship {

    private int teu;

    public ContainerShip(String string, int length, int teu) {
        super(string, length);
        this.teu = teu;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return super.toString()+" container carrier with "+teu+" TEU";
    }

}
```

**Main method**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        ContainerShip cont = new ContainerShip("Name", 100, 4);
        System.out.println(cont.getName());
        cont.setName("new name");
        System.out.println(cont.getName());
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

> Name
>
> new name